# Sending text messages with SL4A

Tags: android, python, sms, sl4a

I am trying to send a text every 10 seconds, but i don't know what is the problem. I apologize for the noob question, but I am a newbie and I could really use some help. Here's the code:

```
import android, time
from time import localtime
droid = android.Android()
now = str(datetime.datetime.now())
while True:
ans = droid.dialogGetInput("Phone Number","","").result
tosend='Wake up!'
droid.smsSend( ans ,tosend )
time.sleep(10)
droid.dialogDismiss()
time.sleep(600)
```

Comment: for one, the indentation is off.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
droid = android.Android()
ans = droid.dialogGetInput("Phone Number","","").result
tosend='Wake up!'
while True:
  droid.smsSend(ans,tosend)
  time.sleep(10)
```